# A space equipped with the quotient topology is $T_0$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, define a relation $\sim$ on X as follows: for $x,y \in X$, $x\sim y$ if every open subset of X that contains $x$ also contains $y$ and every open subset of X that contains $y$ also contains $x$.
Let $Y=X/\sim$ be equipped with the quotient topology from $X$. Show that Y is a $T_0$ space.

The relation is obviously an equivalence relation, and I know that I need to prove for $[x]\neq [y]$ in $Y$, there exist an open set $W$ in Y such that either $[x]\in W$ and $ [y]\notin W$ or $[x]\notin W $and $[y]\in W$.
Thank you

Comment: I know this is silly, but you should probably start with $X$ being $T_1,$ and then show that $Y$ is $T_1.$

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean "Show that $Y$ is a $T_0$ space?" For example, let $X$ be the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space). $X$ is $T_0$ but not $T_1$, and $\sim$ is the trivial equivalence relation, so $X/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $X$, and in particular not $T_1$.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman We assume that X is T1

Comment: Are you sure? If $X$ is $T_1$, then in particular it is $T_0$, and $X$ is always homeomorphic to $X/\sim$. I suppose this solves the exercise, but it does so in an extremely silly way.

Comment: Also, you should make sure you *always* put all relevant assumptions into the question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman you are right, we are supposed to prove this is a T0 space. can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $[x] \neq [y]$. Then $x\not\sim y$. So without loss of generality there's an open set $U\subseteq X$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$. Can you show that the image of $U$ under the quotient map is an open set containing $[x]$ and not containing $[y]$?

Comment: Oh! Thank you! This makes question very clear!